# Google Map V2 on Fragment and ViewPager force stops on changing orientation

Tags: android, android-fragments, landscape

I have a Google Map on one of my fragments, however when I try to change to orientation (to landscape) the app force stops. What is the possible cause and solution for this? I have tried enforcing a portrait orientation bu I think that is bad practice.

Comment: enforcing portrait is not a bad practice, there are some apps that are meant only to be used in the portrait mode. and the crash takes place because on config changes the entire activity is recreated. in that case override the onConfig changes method and do what you want to do with the changes there

Comment: how can i force the onconfig changes?

Comment: please refer to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html and also http://mrbool.com/how-to-manage-screen-configuration-in-android/26879, and http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

Comment: okay. will take time to read.